# If $f'+f''\geq f^2$ show that $\frac{f'}{f''}\leq 1$ for all $x\in(0,+\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a question about this :

> Let a function $f$ with domain $]0,+\infty[$ and codomain $]0,+\infty[$ and twice differentiable with the following inequality :
>   $$f'+f''\geq f^2$$
>
> Show that we have $\dfrac{f'}{f''}\leq 1$ for all $x\in$  $]0,+\infty[$

I have no idea to prove or disprove this .

Thanks.

Comment: How did you try. Could you find an example satisfies this problem?

Comment: @MyGlasses yes take $2e^{-2x}$ it works.I try several others examples but I can't find any counter-example .

Comment: Clearly not but $f(x)=tan(e^{-(x+1)^2})$ works and satisfies the inequality .

Comment: You know $f > 0$ for all points in the domain, so $f^2 > 0$ must hold. By the condition on $f$, then $f' + f'' > 0$, meaning $f' > -f''$. Do you think it's possible to go on from here?

Comment: Also, seems strange that there is no statement about the nature of $f''$. Do we just assume that it's never zero? Maybe there's an example of a function satisfying the differential inequality that has null second derivative somewhere, making the second inequality nonsensical.

Comment: I don't think its true. I tried solving $f' + f'' = f^2$ numerically and found that e.g. with the initial conditions $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$, $f'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ the value of $\frac{f'}{f''}(5)$ is greater than $2.5$.

Comment: @Hyperplane can you show a function ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The ODE might even not be analytically solveable, but I am no expert in this. If you want to look around yourself, this is known as a [Lienard equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard_equation).

Answer (score 1):

Make the substitution :

$f(x)=-y(-e^{-x})$ the initial condition becomes with $x \in ]0;\infty[$ :

$y''(-e^{-x})(-e^{-2x})\geq y(-e^{-x})^2$

So the function $y(-e^{-x})$ is concave and now suppose that $y$ is increasing .

We put $t=-e^{-x}$

We can apply a modified version of the Taylor-Lagrange by Wang ([here](http://www.radford.edu/~wyang/taiwan-nsc06/converseCauchyMeanValue.pdf) leaf 6)
with $a=0$ ,$n=1$ , $0<c<1$ and $-f(x)=y(t)$ we find :

$$y''(c)t^2=(y(t)-y(0)-y'(0)t)2!$$

Moreover for $x=c$ we have :

$$y''(c)c^2=(y(c)-y(0)-y'(0)c)2!$$

But on one hand the function $y$ is concave and negative so :

$y(c)-y(0)-y'(0)c=c(\frac{y(c)-y(0)}{c-0}-y'(0))>0$

On the other hand we have $y''(-e^{-x})<0$ so it's a contradiction and the function is decreasing.

So we have $\frac{f'}{f''}\leq0<1$.